# Arevmath and letter a

Tags: math-mode, fonts, arev

The `arevmath` package offers two different a, available as \origa and \vara (default value). However, adding `\DeclareMathSymbol{a}{\mathalpha}{extraitalic}{50}` in the preamble to turn \origa as the default a, the output is wrong; e.g., $\mathsf{a}$ produces 2, idem for $\mathbf{a}$.

```
\documentclass{article}    
\usepackage{arevmath}

\DeclareMathSymbol{a}{\mathalpha}{extraitalic}{50} % \origa by default

\begin{document}

$a, \mathsf{a}, \mathbf{2}, \vara, \origa, \mathsf{\origa}$ 

\end{document}
```

[image]

How to fix this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Legacy fonts, with only 128 or 256 slots, required much coding gymnastics and many font support files.

For `arevmath` package, for `a`, the tt and tt bold ones might be what you're after. Otherwise, the "round" `a` seems to be the norm.

Quick overview:

[image: zavm]

(Easier to use ttf\otf fonts with `unicode-math` package, though.)

MWE

Font tables / glyph lists:

```
\documentclass{article}    
\usepackage{arevmath}
\usepackage{fonttable}

%\DeclareMathSymbol{b}{\mathalpha}{extraitalic}{50} % 
\newcommand\showfont[6]{\newpage #1-#2-#3-#4 : for #5, #6 = {\usefont{#1}{#2}{#3}{#4}\char#6}\par\xfonttable{#1}{#2}{#3}{#4}}
\newcommand\xshowfont[6]{\par#1-#2-#3-#4 : for #5, #6 = {\usefont{#1}{#2}{#3}{#4}\char#6}}
\begin{document}


\xshowfont{U}{zavm}{m}{n}{nonstandard alternate glyphs, upright}{113}
\xshowfont{U}{zavm}{m}{it}{nonstandard alternate glyphs, italic}{50}
\xshowfont{U}{zavm}{m}{it}{nonstandard alternate glyphs, italic}{139}


\xshowfont{OT1}{zavm}{m}{n}{operators normal}{97}
\xshowfont{OML}{zavm}{m}{it}{letters normal}{97}
\xshowfont{OMS}{zavm}{m}{n}{symbols normal}{65}
\xshowfont{OMX}{mdbch}{m}{n}{largesymbols normal}{74}

\xshowfont{OT1}{zavm}{b}{n}{mathbf normal}{97}
\xshowfont{T1} {fvm} {m}{n}{mathtt normal}{97}
\xshowfont{OMS}{cmsy}{m}{n}{mathcal}{65} 
\xshowfont{U}{rsfs}{m}{n}{mathscr}{65}   
\xshowfont{OML}{zavm}{b}{it}{mathbm}{97}
%\showfont{U}{futm}{m}{n}{mathbb}{1}

%=====
\xshowfont{OT1}{zavm}{b}{n}{operators bold}{97}
\xshowfont{OML}{zavm}{b}{it}{letters bold}{97}
\xshowfont{OMS}{zavm}{b}{n}{symbols bold}{65}
\xshowfont{OMX}{mdbch}{b}{n}{largesymbols bold}{72}
\xshowfont{OT1}{zavm}{b}{n}{mathbf bold}{97}
\xshowfont{T1}{fvm}{b}{n}{mathtt bold}{97}

% with font table

\showfont{U}{zavm}{m}{n}{nonstandard alternate glyphs, upright}{113}
\showfont{U}{zavm}{m}{it}{nonstandard alternate glyphs, italic}{50}


\showfont{OT1}{zavm}{m}{n}{operators normal}{97}
\showfont{OML}{zavm}{m}{it}{letters normal}{97}
\showfont{OMS}{zavm}{m}{n}{symbols normal}{65}
\showfont{OMX}{mdbch}{m}{n}{largesymbols normal}{74}

\showfont{OT1}{zavm}{b}{n}{mathbf normal}{97}
\showfont{T1} {fvm} {m}{n}{mathtt normal}{97}
\showfont{OMS}{cmsy}{m}{n}{mathcal}{65} 
\showfont{U}{rsfs}{m}{n}{mathscr}{65}   
\showfont{OML}{zavm}{b}{it}{mathbm}{97}
%\showfont{U}{futm}{m}{n}{mathbb}{1}

%=====
\showfont{OT1}{zavm}{b}{n}{operators bold}{97}
\showfont{OML}{zavm}{b}{it}{letters bold}{97}
\showfont{OMS}{zavm}{b}{n}{symbols bold}{65}
\showfont{OMX}{mdbch}{b}{n}{largesymbols bold}{72}
\showfont{OT1}{zavm}{b}{n}{mathbf bold}{97}
\showfont{T1}{fvm}{b}{n}{mathtt bold}{97}



%\DeclareSymbolFontAlphabet{\mathnormal}{letters}
%\DeclareSymbolFontAlphabet{\mathit}    {letters}
%\DeclareSymbolFontAlphabet{\mathrm}    {operators}
%\DeclareSymbolFontAlphabet{\mathsf}    {letters}



\end{document}
```

---

*Edit*

Typical legacy font:

[image: a glyph list]

The variant letters are coming from a font file with `U` (="unknown") encoding, meaning a custom arrangement of glyphs, somewhat similar conceptually to the Private Use Area of Unicode.

[image: u encoding]

while 'normal' letters are coming from a 128-slot font file with one of the legacy encodings (`OML`)

[image: oml]

and symbols from the `OMS` encoding:

[image: oms]

and so on for bold, etc.... (The code prints out the various tables.)

The `arevmath` package is working as designed.

The "fix" would probably be to use Unicode-aware packages that can switch over fonts for you depending on which compiler you use, or delve into `unicode-math` package directly and compile with xelatex/lualatex (or maybe re-write `arevmath`? - it was last maintained in 2006).

---

**Mini-example of importing symbols using unicode-math**

Say we have a set of Unicode math fonts to choose from (sans is marked):

[image: font list]

And say we want to use TeX Gyre Schola Math font, but replacing its "round a" sans italic alphanumeric symbols with those from Asana-Math font.

[image: asana]

(Note that direct input symbols and named macro symbols are normalised to the bold-style and math-style currently in force, basically either upright or italic.)

Here is TeX Gyre Schola Math set as the math font, with its style set to ISO, to show the italics flowing through.

[image: schola]

The `range=` option is used to select which symbol(s) to import. We'll make them red to highlight them.

[image: imported]

(Note that `range={sfit,bfsfit}` will import sans italic and bold sans italic for Latin uppercase, Latin lowercase, Greek uppercase, Greek lowercase, and digits; `range=` can take parameters to restrict the import to just one, or a combination, of those, or even to just individual glyphs.)

Do `texdoc unicode-math` for more details.

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{Asana-Math}[Colour=brown]
\setmainfont{Noto Serif}
\usepackage{xparse}



% maths

\newfontfamily\asanamath{Asana}[Extension=.otf,Path=C:/.../tl/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/fonts/opentype/public/asana-math/,
UprightFont =*-Math,
]


\newfontfamily\firamathregular{FiraMath}[Extension=.otf,Path=C:/.../tl/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/fonts/opentype/public/firamath/,
UprightFont =*-Regular,
]

\newfontfamily\gfsneohellenicmath{GFSNeohellenicMath}[Extension=.otf,Path=C:/.../tl/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/fonts/opentype/public/gfsneohellenicmath/,
UprightFont =GFSNeohellenicMath,
]

\newfontfamily\latinmodernmath{latinmodern}[Extension=.otf,Path=C:/.../tl/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/fonts/opentype/public/lm-math/,
UprightFont =*-math,
]

\newfontfamily\libertinusmath{LibertinusMath}[Extension=.otf,Path=C:/.../tl/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/fonts/opentype/public/libertinus-fonts/,
UprightFont =*-Regular,
]

\newfontfamily\stixmath{STIXMath}[Extension=.otf,Path=C:/.../tl/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/fonts/opentype/public/stix/,
UprightFont =*-Regular,
]

\newfontfamily\stixiimath{STIX2Math}[Extension=.otf,Path=C:/.../tl/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/fonts/opentype/public/stix2-otf/,
UprightFont =STIX2Math,
]

\newfontfamily\texgyrebonummath{texgyrebonum}[Extension=.otf,Path=C:/.../tl/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/fonts/opentype/public/tex-gyre-math/,
UprightFont =*-math,
]
%
\newfontfamily\texgyredejavumath{texgyredejavu}[Extension=.otf,Path=C:/.../tl/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/fonts/opentype/public/tex-gyre-math/,
UprightFont =*-math,
]
%
\newfontfamily\texgyrepagellamath{texgyrepagella}[Extension=.otf,Path=C:/.../tl/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/fonts/opentype/public/tex-gyre-math/,
UprightFont =*-math,
]
%
\newfontfamily\texgyrescholamath{texgyreschola}[Extension=.otf,Path=C:/.../tl/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/fonts/opentype/public/tex-gyre-math/,
UprightFont =*-math,
]
%
\newfontfamily\texgyretermesmath{texgyretermes}[Extension=.otf,Path=C:/.../tl/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/fonts/opentype/public/tex-gyre-math/,
UprightFont =*-math,
]
%
\newfontfamily\xitsmathbold{XITSMath}[Extension=.otf,Path=C:/.../tl/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/fonts/opentype/public/xits/,
UprightFont =*-Bold,
]
%
\newfontfamily\xitsmathregular{XITSMath}[Extension=.otf,Path=C:/.../tl/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/fonts/opentype/public/xits/,
UprightFont =*-Regular,
]







%-------------------------------------------------------------
\ExplSyntaxOn



        \cs_generate_variant:Nn 
            \seq_gset_split:Nnn 
            { cno }


\tl_new:N \g_fc_namespace_tl




%------------------
    \cs_set:Npn \fc_funcsymbolcompare:n #1 { 
    % 1=font switch name

   \tl_set:Nx
    \l_tmpa_tl
    {
                #1
        }
    \use:c
        { \tl_use:N \g_tmpa_tl } % sample name taking font name as parameter
            { \tl_use:N \l_tmpa_tl } % font name from seq
            { \tl_use:N \g_tmpb_tl } % symbol
}


%------------------
    \cs_set:Npn \fc_funcprintesc:n #1 { 
    % 1=string
\exp_args:NNf   \str_set:Nn \l_tmpa_str { #1 }
                        \group_begin:
                        \color{blue} 
                        \usefont{T1}{zi4}{b}{n} 
                        \large
                        \textbackslash
                        {\str_use:N \l_tmpa_str}
                        \group_end:
                        
}

%------------------
    \cs_set:Npn \fc_funcprint:n #1 { 
    % 1=string
\exp_args:NNf   \str_set:Nn \l_tmpa_str { #1 }
                        \str_remove_all:Nn \l_tmpa_str {\protect}
\exp_args:NNxx
                        \str_replace_all:Nnn 
                                \l_tmpa_str 
                                {\space\space\c_left_brace_str} 
                                {\c_left_brace_str}
\exp_args:NNxx
                        \str_replace_all:Nnn 
                                \l_tmpa_str 
                                {\space\c_left_brace_str} 
                                {\c_left_brace_str}

                        \group_begin:
                        \color{blue} 
                        \usefont{T1}{zi4}{b}{n} 
                        \large

                        {\str_use:N \l_tmpa_str}

                        \group_end:
                        
}









%****************************************************
%* utility commands
%****************************************************
%--------------------
\newcommand\mfssamplewidth{0.5in}
\NewDocumentCommand { \psymcmp } { m m } { 
% 1=font name
% 2=symbol(s)
            \use:c { #1 }
            \tex_par:D
            \colorbox
                    {blue!7}
                    {
                        \makebox[\mfssamplewidth][c]{\large #2}
                    } 
        {\usefont{T1}{lmr}{m}{n} \ #1} 

}


%****************************************************
%* main commands
%****************************************************
%--------------------
\NewDocumentCommand { \mfsloadaseq } { o m +m } { 
% 1=namespace
% 2=seq name
% 3=data

                \IfNoValueTF { #1 } 
                        { \tl_clear:N \g_fc_namespace_tl } 
                        { \tl_gset:Nn \g_fc_namespace_tl { #1 } }


    \cs_if_free:cT
            { g_fc_rwe \g_fc_namespace_tl #2 _seq }
            { \seq_new:c
                    { g_fc_rwe \g_fc_namespace_tl #2 _seq } 
            }
    \seq_gclear:c 
            { g_fc_rwe \g_fc_namespace_tl #2 _seq } 
    \seq_gset_split:cno 
            { g_fc_rwe \g_fc_namespace_tl #2 _seq } 
            { , } 
            { #3 }



}



%****************************************************
%*
%****************************************************
%--------------------
\NewDocumentCommand { \mfssymbolcompare } { o m m m } { 
% 1=namespace
% 2=seq name
% 3=sample name
% 4=symbol

                \IfNoValueTF { #1 } 
                        { \tl_clear:N \g_fc_namespace_tl } 
                        { \tl_gset:Nn \g_fc_namespace_tl { #1 } }

        \tl_gset:Nn \g_tmpa_tl { #3 } 
        \tl_gset:Nn \g_tmpb_tl { #4 } 


        \group_begin:               
            \exp_args:Nx
            \seq_map_function:cN 
                    { g_fc_rwe \g_fc_namespace_tl #2 _seq } 
                    \fc_funcsymbolcompare:n
        \group_end:


}


%****************************************************
%*
%****************************************************
%-------------------- Meta



\tl_new:N \l_myparmb_tl
%-------------------- MetaC
\NewDocumentCommand \mmc { s m } { % 1=run, 2 = text
                        \tl_set:Nn \l_myparmb_tl { #2 }


                \IfBooleanTF { #1 } 
            {
                    \fc_funcprint:n { \tl_use:N \l_myparmb_tl }
                    \space $\mapsto$ \space  \l_myparmb_tl
                } 
            {
                    \fc_funcprintesc:n { \tl_use:N \l_myparmb_tl }
                } 

}





%-------------------- xMetaV
\NewDocumentCommand \xmmv { s O{\texttt} m } { % 1 = font, 2 = text
\tl_set:Nn \l_tmpa_tl { #2 {  \tl_to_str:n {#3} } 
        \IfBooleanT {#1} { \space $\mapsto$\space #3 }
          }
\tl_use:N \l_tmpa_tl

}



\ExplSyntaxOff


\newcommand\mtable[1]{% 1-(text)font for mmode
\begin{tabular}{lll}
\rowcolor{brown!15}
generic macros
& specific macros
& direct input
\\
\mmc*{$\symsfup{a}x$}
& \mmc*{$\msansa x$}
& \xmmv*[#1]{$$}
\\
\mmc*{$\symsfit{a}x$}
& \mmc*{$\mitsansa x$}
&
\\
\mmc*{$\symbfsfup{a}x$}
& \mmc*{$\mbfsansa x$}
&
\\
\mmc*{$\symbfsfit{a}x$}
& \mmc*{$\mbfitsansa x$}
&
\\
\end{tabular}
}



\begin{document}



\mfsloadaseq[sam]{mfonts}{
asanamath
,firamathregular
,gfsneohellenicmath
,latinmodernmath
,libertinusmath
,stixmath
,stixiimath
,texgyrebonummath
,texgyredejavumath
,texgyrepagellamath
,texgyrescholamath
,texgyretermesmath
,xitsmathbold
,xitsmathregular
}





\paragraph{Sample of random Unicode math fonts}\ \par

\renewcommand\mfssamplewidth{2in}
\par\bigskip\mfssymbolcompare[sam]{mfonts}{psymcmp}{\fbox{}}


\newpage
\paragraph{Asana-Math}
\ \par\xmmv{\setmathfont{Asana-Math}[Colour=brown]}
\par\bigskip\mtable{\asanamath}

\paragraph{TeXGyreSchola-Math}
\setmathfont[bold-style=ISO,math-style=ISO]{TeXGyreSchola-Math}
\ \par\xmmv{\setmathfont[bold-style=ISO, math-style=ISO]{TeXGyreSchola-Math}}
\par\bigskip\mtable{\texgyrescholamath}

\paragraph{Sans italic symbols from Asana-Math}
\setmathfont{Asana-Math}[range={sfit,bfsfit},Colour=red]
\ \par\xmmv{\setmathfont{Asana-Math}[range={sfit, bfsfit}, Colour=red]}
\par\bigskip\mtable{\texgyrescholamath}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Excellent. I have deleted my answer. +1